# Serialization of the received stratistics into a json file

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Good afternoon! I am new to JAVA and JSON. I'm using Jackson. The program does the following from the incoming JSON file:

1. Gives out a list of people between the ages of 20 and 30;
2. Unique list of cities;
3. The number of people with an age interval of 0-10, 11-20, 21-30, etc.
   The program consists of two classes

Main.java

```
package com.testsample;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        try {

            List<Data> data = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(Paths.get("C:\\dataClients.json").toFile(), Data[].class));

            List<Data> age20to30 = data
                    .stream()
                    .filter(p -> p.getAge() >= 20 && p.getAge() < 30)
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getLastName() + " " + p.getFirstName()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            age20to30.forEach(System.out::println);

            Set<String> cities = data
                    .stream()
                    .map(Data::getCity)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
            cities.forEach(System.out::println);

            Map<String, Long> byAges = data
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getAgeGroup, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
            System.out.println(byAges);


        } catch (JsonParseException jsonParseException) {
            jsonParseException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Data.java

```
package com.testsample;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class Data {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String city;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    Data() {

    }


    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dob) {
        if (dob.isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
            dob = dob.minusYears(100);
        }
        this.dateOfBirth = dob;
    }

    public Data(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String city, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.city = city;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public int getAge() {
        return Period.between(dateOfBirth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getAgeGroup() {
        int age = getAge();
        if (age < 11) {
            return "0..10";
        }
        return (age / 10 * 10 + 1) + ".." + ((age / 10 + 1) * 10);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id = " + id + ", age=" + getAge() + ", firstName = " + firstName + ", lastName = " + lastName + ", dateOfBirth = " + dateOfBirth + ", city = " + city + "]";
    }
}
```

Json file

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Lesley",
        "lastName": "Bryan",
        "dateOfBirth": "1961-11-28",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Edward",
        "lastName": "Houston",
        "dateOfBirth": "1992-10-05",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "Donald",
        "lastName": "Ross",
        "dateOfBirth": "1979-12-10",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Kelly",
        "dateOfBirth": "2004-03-17",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "firstName": "Anthony",
        "lastName": "McKinney",
        "dateOfBirth": "1968-03-06",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Stewart",
        "dateOfBirth": "1973-04-11",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "firstName": "Christopher",
        "lastName": "Austin",
        "dateOfBirth": "1974-12-28",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "firstName": "Alvin",
        "lastName": "Hodge",
        "dateOfBirth": "1958-11-25",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "firstName": "Gerald",
        "lastName": "Higgins",
        "dateOfBirth": "1955-06-28",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "firstName": "Amos",
        "lastName": "Owens",
        "dateOfBirth": "2001-01-16",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "firstName": "Christian",
        "lastName": "Bishop",
        "dateOfBirth": "1950-11-14",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "Caldwell",
        "dateOfBirth": "1980-12-08",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "firstName": "Brian",
        "lastName": "Heath",
        "dateOfBirth": "2002-09-23",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "14",
        "firstName": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Anthony",
        "dateOfBirth": "1992-01-08",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "firstName": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Watson",
        "dateOfBirth": "1991-07-27",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "firstName": "Charles",
        "lastName": "Stafford",
        "dateOfBirth": "1990-01-26",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "firstName": "Steven",
        "lastName": "Merritt",
        "dateOfBirth": "1963-12-04",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "dateOfBirth": "1952-04-22",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "19",
        "firstName": "Mervin",
        "lastName": "Lewis",
        "dateOfBirth": "1995-10-27",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Marsh",
        "dateOfBirth": "1963-12-10",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "21",
        "firstName": "Piers",
        "lastName": "Harrington",
        "dateOfBirth": "1985-04-27",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "22",
        "firstName": "Matthew",
        "lastName": "O’Brien’",
        "dateOfBirth": "1959-01-19",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "23",
        "firstName": "Blaze",
        "lastName": "Williamson",
        "dateOfBirth": "1959-11-26",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "24",
        "firstName": "Ethan",
        "lastName": "Harrison",
        "dateOfBirth": "1999-08-27",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "25",
        "firstName": "Blake",
        "lastName": "Dennis",
        "dateOfBirth": "2003-09-12",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "26",
        "firstName": "Isaac",
        "lastName": "Jordan",
        "dateOfBirth": "1994-08-08",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "27",
        "firstName": "Winfred",
        "lastName": "Washington",
        "dateOfBirth": "1977-04-24",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "28",
        "firstName": "Brent",
        "lastName": "Hoover",
        "dateOfBirth": "1986-09-28",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "29",
        "firstName": "Jacob",
        "lastName": "Benson",
        "dateOfBirth": "1954-12-04",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "30",
        "firstName": "Thomas",
        "lastName": "Martin",
        "dateOfBirth": "1954-11-18",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "31",
        "firstName": "Ferdinand",
        "lastName": "Douglas",
        "dateOfBirth": "1989-01-28",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "32",
        "firstName": "Cecil",
        "lastName": "Sutton",
        "dateOfBirth": "1982-08-16",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "33",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Warner",
        "dateOfBirth": "1950-03-13",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "34",
        "firstName": "Williamя",
        "lastName": "Gallagher",
        "dateOfBirth": "1997-01-04",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "35",
        "firstName": "Frank",
        "lastName": "Hensley",
        "dateOfBirth": "1980-03-15",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "36",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Summers",
        "dateOfBirth": "1981-08-01",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "37",
        "firstName": "Melvin",
        "lastName": "Allison",
        "dateOfBirth": "1982-10-08",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "38",
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "Bell",
        "dateOfBirth": "1966-06-27",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "39",
        "firstName": "Edward",
        "lastName": "Gordon",
        "dateOfBirth": "1986-07-20",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "40",
        "firstName": "Charles",
        "lastName": "Hicks",
        "dateOfBirth": "1960-06-12",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "41",
        "firstName": "Joshua",
        "lastName": "Wheeler",
        "dateOfBirth": "1979-02-11",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "42",
        "firstName": "Leonard",
        "lastName": "Hall",
        "dateOfBirth": "1974-09-16",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "43",
        "firstName": "Jerome",
        "lastName": "Hill",
        "dateOfBirth": "2002-06-04",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "44",
        "firstName": "Matthew",
        "lastName": "Hawkins",
        "dateOfBirth": "1968-02-22",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "45",
        "firstName": "Archibald",
        "lastName": "Russell",
        "dateOfBirth": "1965-10-29",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "46",
        "firstName": "Charles",
        "lastName": "Little",
        "dateOfBirth": "1954-09-07",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "47",
        "firstName": "Neil",
        "lastName": "Dean",
        "dateOfBirth": "1979-12-31",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "48",
        "firstName": "Jeremy",
        "lastName": "Norris",
        "dateOfBirth": "1955-07-21",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "49",
        "firstName": "Christopher",
        "lastName": "Holland",
        "dateOfBirth": "1994-10-25",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "50",
        "firstName": "Myron",
        "lastName": "Carroll",
        "dateOfBirth": "1982-01-16",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "51",
        "firstName": "Hugo",
        "lastName": "Long",
        "dateOfBirth": "1962-05-25",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "52",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Thornton",
        "dateOfBirth": "1969-02-02",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "53",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Eaton",
        "dateOfBirth": "1960-02-27",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "54",
        "firstName": "Abner",
        "lastName": "Joseph",
        "dateOfBirth": "1960-01-29",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "55",
        "firstName": "Ethan",
        "lastName": "McDowell",
        "dateOfBirth": "1983-07-11",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "56",
        "firstName": "Anthony",
        "lastName": "Barton",
        "dateOfBirth": "1972-12-09",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "57",
        "firstName": "Anthony",
        "lastName": "Green",
        "dateOfBirth": "2003-01-26",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "58",
        "firstName": "Ronald",
        "lastName": "Gilbert",
        "dateOfBirth": "1988-05-28",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "59",
        "firstName": "Brendan",
        "lastName": "White",
        "dateOfBirth": "1975-07-02",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "60",
        "firstName": "Christopher",
        "lastName": "Richards",
        "dateOfBirth": "1979-09-23",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "61",
        "firstName": "Buck",
        "lastName": "Sanders",
        "dateOfBirth": "1956-05-03",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "62",
        "firstName": "Griffin",
        "lastName": "Cannon",
        "dateOfBirth": "1962-01-05",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "63",
        "firstName": "Evan",
        "lastName": "Nichols",
        "dateOfBirth": "1960-01-18",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "64",
        "firstName": "Peregrine",
        "lastName": "Horton",
        "dateOfBirth": "1960-10-11",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "65",
        "firstName": "Paul",
        "lastName": "Hampton",
        "dateOfBirth": "1991-08-06",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "66",
        "firstName": "Jacob",
        "lastName": "Fox",
        "dateOfBirth": "1983-05-18",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "67",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Griffith",
        "dateOfBirth": "1971-01-03",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "68",
        "firstName": "Jack",
        "lastName": "May",
        "dateOfBirth": "1984-09-28",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "69",
        "firstName": "Harold",
        "lastName": "Owen",
        "dateOfBirth": "1965-08-17",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "70",
        "firstName": "Abraham",
        "lastName": "Hardy",
        "dateOfBirth": "1981-10-26",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "71",
        "firstName": "Frederick",
        "lastName": "Allen",
        "dateOfBirth": "1987-08-19",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "72",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Thompson",
        "dateOfBirth": "1992-09-27",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "73",
        "firstName": "Bertram",
        "lastName": "Hopkins",
        "dateOfBirth": "2001-02-23",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "74",
        "firstName": "Christopher",
        "lastName": "Burns",
        "dateOfBirth": "1962-05-22",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "75",
        "firstName": "Vernon",
        "lastName": "Perry",
        "dateOfBirth": "1966-10-17",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "76",
        "firstName": "Oliver",
        "lastName": "Webster",
        "dateOfBirth": "1955-03-13",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "77",
        "firstName": "Joshua",
        "lastName": "Ball",
        "dateOfBirth": "1972-03-08",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "78",
        "firstName": "Christopher",
        "lastName": "Griffin",
        "dateOfBirth": "1994-09-26",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "79",
        "firstName": "Sherman",
        "lastName": "Pearson",
        "dateOfBirth": "1959-01-31",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "80",
        "firstName": "Gavin",
        "lastName": "Barber",
        "dateOfBirth": "2003-02-16",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "81",
        "firstName": "Brian",
        "lastName": "Mills",
        "dateOfBirth": "1980-10-17",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "82",
        "firstName": "Herbert",
        "lastName": "Grant",
        "dateOfBirth": "1991-11-28",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "83",
        "firstName": "Christopher",
        "lastName": "Sherman",
        "dateOfBirth": "2002-04-08",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "84",
        "firstName": "Patrick",
        "lastName": "Morrison",
        "dateOfBirth": "1979-07-13",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "85",
        "firstName": "Kristopher",
        "lastName": "Nash",
        "dateOfBirth": "1966-09-10",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "86",
        "firstName": "Henry",
        "lastName": "Hood",
        "dateOfBirth": "1975-10-03",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "87",
        "firstName": "Edward",
        "lastName": "Walsh",
        "dateOfBirth": "2004-04-16",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "88",
        "firstName": "Williamя",
        "lastName": "Francis",
        "dateOfBirth": "1969-08-06",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "89",
        "firstName": "Leo",
        "lastName": "Richardson",
        "dateOfBirth": "1989-12-19",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "90",
        "firstName": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Day",
        "dateOfBirth": "1954-06-06",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "91",
        "firstName": "Charles",
        "lastName": "Cross",
        "dateOfBirth": "1955-02-23",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "92",
        "firstName": "Alban",
        "lastName": "Fields",
        "dateOfBirth": "1953-09-03",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "93",
        "firstName": "Paul",
        "lastName": "Rodgers",
        "dateOfBirth": "1966-10-07",
        "city": "Sheffield"
    },
    {
        "id": "94",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Gregory",
        "dateOfBirth": "1965-11-23",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "95",
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Patrick",
        "dateOfBirth": "1967-04-27",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "96",
        "firstName": "Jacob",
        "lastName": "Walters",
        "dateOfBirth": "1952-12-09",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "97",
        "firstName": "Kenneth",
        "lastName": "Thomas",
        "dateOfBirth": "1973-05-16",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "98",
        "firstName": "Ernest",
        "lastName": "Cobb",
        "dateOfBirth": "1985-09-05",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "99",
        "firstName": "Joseph",
        "lastName": "Small",
        "dateOfBirth": "1965-03-06",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "100",
        "firstName": "Basil",
        "lastName": "Stephens",
        "dateOfBirth": "1964-07-29",
        "city": "London"
    }
]
```

The result of the program is as follows:

```
[id = 14, age=28, firstName = Mark, lastName = Anthony, dateOfBirth = 1992-01-08, city = London]
[id = 34, age=23, firstName = Williamя, lastName = Gallagher, dateOfBirth = 1997-01-04, city = Nottingham]
[id = 82, age=28, firstName = Herbert, lastName = Grant, dateOfBirth = 1991-11-28, city = Southampton–Portsmouth]
[id = 78, age=26, firstName = Christopher, lastName = Griffin, dateOfBirth = 1994-09-26, city = Nottingham]
[id = 65, age=29, firstName = Paul, lastName = Hampton, dateOfBirth = 1991-08-06, city = Sheffield]
[id = 24, age=21, firstName = Ethan, lastName = Harrison, dateOfBirth = 1999-08-27, city = Southampton–Portsmouth]
[id = 49, age=25, firstName = Christopher, lastName = Holland, dateOfBirth = 1994-10-25, city = Sheffield]
[id = 2, age=28, firstName = Edward, lastName = Houston, dateOfBirth = 1992-10-05, city = Southampton–Portsmouth]
[id = 26, age=26, firstName = Isaac, lastName = Jordan, dateOfBirth = 1994-08-08, city = London]
[id = 19, age=24, firstName = Mervin, lastName = Lewis, dateOfBirth = 1995-10-27, city = Birmingham–Wolverhampton]
[id = 72, age=28, firstName = Peter, lastName = Thompson, dateOfBirth = 1992-09-27, city = Sheffield]
[id = 15, age=29, firstName = Mark, lastName = Watson, dateOfBirth = 1991-07-27, city = Nottingham]
Birmingham–Wolverhampton
Glasgow
Leeds–Bradford
Liverpool
London
Manchester-Salford
Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland
Nottingham
Sheffield
Southampton–Portsmouth
{11..20=10, 21..30=12, 31..40=19, 41..50=16, 51..60=21, 61..70=21, 71..80=1}
```

Now I need to serialize all received data into one file. They tell me that I need to create another class that will collect the results of the program, and then serialize it into a json file.
Please help in the implementation of this task.
P.S.: All names, surnames and dates from the json file were obtained at random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the obtained output to HashMap and that hashMap can be written to a file using ObjectMapper like this.

```
package com.testsample;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    try {

        List<Data> data = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(Paths.get("C:\\dataClients.json").toFile(), Data[].class));

        List<Data> age20to30 = data
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getAge() >= 20 && p.getAge() < 30)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getLastName() + " " + p.getFirstName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        age20to30.forEach(System.out::println);

        Set<String> cities = data
                .stream()
                .map(Data::getCity)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        cities.forEach(System.out::println);

        Map<String, Long> byAges = data
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getAgeGroup, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(byAges);

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("age20To30", age20to30);
        map.put("cities", cities);
        map.put("byAges", byAges);  

        // convert map to JSON file
        mapper.writeValue(Paths.get("C:\\dataOutput.json").toFile(), map);


    } catch (JsonParseException jsonParseException) {
        jsonParseException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Now the content of the output file will be like below

```
{
  "cities": [
    "Birmingham–Wolverhampton",
    "Glasgow",
    "Leeds–Bradford",
    "Liverpool",
    "London",
    "Manchester-Salford",
    "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland",
    "Nottingham",
    "Sheffield",
    "Southampton–Portsmouth"
  ],
  "byAges": {
    "11..20": 10,
    "21..30": 12,
    "31..40": 19,
    "41..50": 16,
    "51..60": 21,
    "61..70": 21,
    "71..80": 1
  },
  "age20To30": [
    {
      "id": 14,
      "firstName": "Mark",
      "lastName": "Anthony",
      "dateOfBirth": "1992-01-08",
      "city": "London"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "firstName": "Williamя",
      "lastName": "Gallagher",
      "dateOfBirth": "1997-01-04",
      "city": "Nottingham"
    }
  ]
}
```